# What is wrong in reading Nifi flowfile and creating python(pandas)dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I have scenario where I am getting the file(stream:flowfile of NIFI) as of type csv file,
then creating the dataframe and dumping it thats it.
But after creating the dataframe the structure of the file got disturbed, if I open 
the same flowfile on my disk i could see clear structure with columns separated with
tab, but with python dataframe I am not getting the same structure, if I get same structure i can person row manipulation.

```
Here What I am doing:
1: using ExecuteSQL processor, I am getting database record,

2: then passing this record to ConvertRecord processor  to convert this avro record type csv file separated by tab.
[enter image description here][1]
3: Then the reading flowfile(step 2 folowfile)  as python data using ExecuteStreamCommand, coz I am want to perform some action on the database record, to do this my record structure has been changed  in data frame.

The flow file generated from ConvertRecord is ...

[enter image description here][2]


The out put of the dataframe is ..

[enter image description here][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4P97.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU3ke.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcICS.png

sample python code...

import sys, csv;
import pandas as pd

class CustomPythonScript():
    df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin)
    output = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Comment: @mattyb , Any pointers for me.

Comment: Since it's tab-delimited, don't you need `sep='\t'` in your `read_csv()` call?

Comment: Yes Yes Mattyb, after adding it went way, thank you .